# any open source IDE with the possibility to go the declaration of a function, a variable..?

Tags: php, ide, declaration

any open source IDE with the possibility to go the declaration of a function, a variable, a class... presing a key(s)??

Apart from Netbeans and Eclipse.

Regards

Javi

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: I suppose PHP, Java, or C++ :P

Comment: Any reason for the 'apart from Netbeans and Eclipse'?

Comment: yes...but would difficult to explain..

Comment: When you say open source do you really just mean free?  Most people tend to get the two terms confused.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), and *e.g.* [vim](http://www.vim.org).  In reality, "ctags" is a gross understatement, as you can generate an index of function and variable "tags" for almost any language.

Answer (score 0):

emacs or vim would allow you to do this for most languages.  Not really an IDE though.

Comment: ctags in VI lets you use the command gd (for locals) or gD (for globals)   For emacs see http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/JumpToDefinition

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use [PHPDesigner](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/downloads.php) which does have a free edition.   What you appear to be asking about is called "code completition" which this editor does, along with the ability to right click a custom function and "Go to definition" or hit F1 to view the PHP Manual on that function.

Answer (score 0):

May be [Komodo edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/) ? It's close to Eclipse and Netbeans, but much more simpler. You can go to declaration of function or variable by a custom shortcut key or just CTRL + Click on the desired var/func.